# IIS6 wildcard mapping overriding regular mappings

Tags: iis, wildcard, handler-mappings

Has anyone ever run into a problem where a wildcard mapping was overriding a standard mapping?  Is this expected behavior? In my case I have my wildcard mapped to aspnet_isapi.dll for a cms application and then the .iirf extension mapped to the .iirf dll. However, I noticed that the .iirf requests are going to asp.net and erroring out rather then going to the .iirf dll.  When I remove the aspnet wildcard mapping, then it seems to work properly.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this occur.  I bet it's a dependency that is not working.  The one example I can think of is if you are depending on default docs, then a wildcard mapping will break the default docs, causing .NET to handle that request before .iirf gets a chance.

So the wildcard mapping isn't overriding .iirf, but it is overriding the default doc behavior.